# d3dx11.h missing?

Tags: c++, directx-11

So I've reinstalled directx11 a couple times and even went to the Microsoft website and got the SDK pack that has all the direct x cabinet files in it. Anyone have any idea why i keep getting this error then? I know why it is saying it but more looking for the solution to it.

> 1>c:\users\vaughn\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\myfirstapp\myfirstapp\main.cpp(5): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you add the necessary folder into your include directories?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's what you need to do in VS 2010 (it looks a bit different in VS 2008 and earlier):

Go to your project's properties | Configuration Properties | VC++ Directories. Edit line called Include Directories by adding path to DirectX header files. As for June 2010 SDK it may be something like:

32 bit Win: C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include

64 bit Win: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include

Next you are most likely to get a linker's error (missing .lib files). Just go to your project's properties | Configuration Properties | VC++ Directories again, but this time edit Library Directories and add to one of the following paths:

32 bit Win: C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86

64 bit Win: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64

If you installed other version of SDK or installed it to non-default directory change given paths accordingly. Also make sure you added d3d11.lib (and maybe d3dx11.lib as well) to Linker | Additional Dependencies.

General rule is that any time you #include <> files your IDE needs to know where to find them. VC++ Directories is one way of doing that in Visual Studio. But sole inclusion of headers is (in most cases) not enough - you need to tell your linker where to look for precompiled binaries described by those headers. That what you do by adding the second path to Library Directories.

Comment: Okay I'm going to go give this a try. I thought I did this because that is what the assignments instructions told me to do but I'll double check everything.

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out I was missing the VC++ directories and the linker libraries for Direct X11.

Comment: What about using environment variable %DXSDK_DIR%/Include ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you get the latest [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6812).  It has the header files.  If all you got were cabinet files, you got the wrong SDK.

Comment: I downloaded that and it still tells me that it is unable to find it? If I comment out the line requesting access to the file it works but then it makes me also comment out the d3dx10.h file as well and it loads fine.

Comment: Can you search your system for d3dx*.h to see where the correct header files were installed to?

Comment: It didn't pop up even after reinstalling like 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for DX12, I was missing d3dx12.h

See [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn708058(v=vs.85).aspx) page.

In case the page moves, the relevant line appears to be

"**d3dx12.h is available separately from the Direct3D 12 headers**. You can download d3dx12.h by navigating into any of the source files for the Direct3D 12 projects at [GitHub/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples)"

Comment: The DirectX SDK is legacy, and D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are deprecated. For a list of replacements, see [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/). D3DX12 is not part of the Windows SDK or the DirectX SDK. It's intended to just be copied into your project, it is provided on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Templates/DirectX12App/Common/d3dx12.h) under the MIT license. It is also included in various DirectX 12 VS templates including [these](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki).

Comment: Note blob link is now [here](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/)